# Adding values to pandas DataFrame given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to find the most efficient way to do this. 
Say I have a DataFrame df1 that looks like:

```
   time_start  time_end    
0  1548102229  1548102232  
1  1548102239  1548102242 
2  1548102249  1548102252
3  1548102259  1548102262
```

and another DataFrame df2 that looks like:

```
   timestamp   state    
0  1548102231  A  
1  1548102241  A 
2  1548102248  B
3  1548102251  B
```

Is there a way to add 'state' to df1 given the condition of df2['timestamp'] being between df1['time_start'] and df1['time_end'] arriving to:

```
   time_start  time_end    state
0  1548102229  1548102232  A
1  1548102239  1548102242  A
2  1548102249  1548102252  N/A
3  1548102259  1548102262  B
```

Comment: That is a good question, i actually have not come across that case, but it is bound to happen eventually. If that is the case I'd like to take the first state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `IntervalIndex` and `get_indexer`, then we assign back after `.loc`

```
idx=pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['time_start'], df1['time_end'], closed='both')
indexmatch=idx.get_indexer(df2.timestamp)
df1['New']=df2.loc[indexmatch,'state'].values
df1
   time_start    time_end  New
0  1548102229  1548102232    A
1  1548102239  1548102242    A
2  1548102249  1548102252  NaN
3  1548102259  1548102262    B
```

Update

```
idx=pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['time_start'], df1['time_end'], closed='both')
indexmatch=idx.get_indexer(df2.timestamp)
dfcopy=df1.copy()
df1=df1.loc[indexmatch]
df1['New']=df2.loc[indexmatch,'state'].values
df1.groupby(['time_start','time_end'],as_index=False).New.sum().combine_first(dfcopy)
```

Comment: What if df2 has a different length than df1 and i was trying to find if there was a value in df2 with a timestamp that would fall between time_start and time_end to fill the state in df1?

I know for sure that for any given period of time only one state is present, that being A or B but that state can be logged multiple times.

Comment: This is getting super close. I only have an issue with the last line:
df1.groupby(['time_start','time_end'],as_index=False).New.sum().combine_first(dfcopy)

The sum() part is giving me an unexpected result. If df1['New'] is an integer it sums up the states for the amount or occurances. If it is a string it does a string sum, so if there are more than 1 logged states it would give me values like AAA if string or if state A=1 it would give me 3. Trying to do without the sum but seems that combine_first does not like it.

Comment: never mind, i just ended up doing
df1.groupby(['time_start','time_end'],as_index=False).first()

i think the  combine_first(dfcopy) is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`np.less_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.0/reference/generated/numpy.less_equal.html) and [`np.greater_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.2/reference/generated/numpy.greater_equal.html) `outer` ufuncs

```
c = np.less_equal.outer(df2.timestamp, df.time_end) & \
    np.greater_equal.outer(df2.timestamp, df.time_start)

df['state'] = df2.state.values[c.argmax(1)]
```

Then correct all `False` results

```
df.loc[~c.any(1), 'state'] = np.nan

    time_start  time_end    state
0   1548102229  1548102232  A
1   1548102239  1548102242  A
2   1548102249  1548102252  NaN
3   1548102259  1548102262  B
```

Comment: I guess the question to your approach would be the same:
What if df2 has a different length than df1 and i was trying to find if there was a value in df2 with a timestamp that would fall between time_start and time_end to fill the state in df1? I know for sure that for any given period of time only one state is present, that being A or B but that state can be logged multiple times.